# Find text file containing a given text ignoring new lines and spaces?

Tags: grep

I have a string like: `"thisissometext"`. I want to find all text files inside a given directory (recursively) that containg this string, or any variations of it with white spaces and/or newlines in the middle of it. For example, a text file containing `"this is sometext"`, or `"this\n issometext"`, `"this\n isso  metext"`  should show up in the search. How can I do this?

Comment: before I start: no python?

Comment: @JacobVlijm you can use python if you like.

Comment: @JacobVlijm If you know how to do it in python, please do.

Comment: And so I did :)

Comment: Can the spaces / newlines be found only at fixed positions (i.e. only after / before a word?)? Or can they be found in any position (like "th\isisso metext")?

Comment: @kos It is in the question: *this string, or any variations of it with white spaces and/or newlines in the middle of it*

Comment: Just curious, but did you try out the answers?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm on it. So far `heemayl`'s answer seems to work fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the newer versions of GNU `grep` (that has the `-z` option) you can use this one liner:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec grep -lz 'this[[:space:]]*is[[:space:]]*some[[:space:]]*text' {} +
```

Considering the whitespaces can come in between the words only.

If you just want to search all files recursively starting from current directory, you don't need `find`, you can just use `grep -r` (recursive). `find` can be used to be selective on the files to search e.g. choose files of which directory to exclude. So, simply:

```
grep -rlz 'this[[:space:]]*is[[:space:]]*some[[:space:]]*text' .
```

- The main trick here is `-z`, it will treat the each line of input stream ended in ASCII NUL instead of new line, as a result we can match newlines by using usual methods.
- `[[:space:]]` character class pattern indicates any whitespace characters including space, tab, CR, LF etc. So, we can use it to match all the whitespace characters that can come in between the words.
- `grep -l` will print only the file names that having any of the desired patterns. If you want to print the matches also, use `-H` instead of `-l`.

On the other hand, if the whitespaces can come at any places rather than the words, this would loose its good look:

```bsh
grep -rlz
't[[:space:]]*h[[:space:]]*i[[:space:]]*s[[:space:]]*i[[:space:]]*\
s[[:space:]]*s[[:space:]]*o[[:space:]]*m[[:space:]]*e[[:space:]]*\
t[[:space:]]*e[[:space:]]*x[[:space:]]*t' .
```

With `-P` (PCRE) option you can replace the `[[:space:]]` with `\s` (this would look much nicer):

```bsh
grep -rlzP 't\s*h\s*i\s*s\s*i\s*s\s*s\s*o\s*m\s*e\s*\
t\s*e\s*x\s*t' .
```

Using @steeldriver's suggestion to get `sed` to generate the pattern for us would be the best option:

```
grep -rlzP "$(sed 's/./\\s*&/2g' <<< "thisissometext")" .
```

Comment: Again, this does not work on *this string, or any variations of it with white spaces and/or newlines in the middle of it*, Only if they appear on whole words.

Comment: @JacobVlijm You were right..i had misunderstood it..fixed..

Comment: @heemayl you could maybe do something like `grep -zP "$(sed 's/./\\s*&/2g' <<< "thisissometext")"` to take some of the tedium out of extending your approach to arbitrary amounts of whitespace between *any* characters

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks....yeah..that would do great..i have added that..

Comment: Can you specify which version of `grep` do I need for this to work? (And how do I find by `grep` version?) Thanks.

Comment: @becko You can find `grep` version by `grep --version` .. i am using 2.16..i can't recall from which version it included `-z`..use `man grep | grep -- '--null-data'`, you will get it if your `grep` supports it..

Comment: Why is this wrapped in a find-exec? Why not just use grep's -r recursive flag?

Comment: @Oli if the situation is at is right now `grep -r` is the way to go..`find` is used to if OP wants to be more selective on the files.. :)

Comment: the spaces need not be between words. In fact, the text I want to search for is a sequence of characters. There are no "words".  The last command using `sed` seems to work fine.

Comment: @becko Well..then check the last three solutions..i have mentioned that clearly too..  :)

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I +1 your answer ;). It seems to work fine. If I have no issues I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7):

You can delete all whitespace and grep it:

```
tr -d '[[:space:]]' < foo | grep thisissometext
```

Extending:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for i; do tr -d "[[:space:]]" < "$i" | grep -q thisissometext && printf "%s\n" "$i"; done' _ {} +
```

The `bash` command, expanded:

```bsh
for i
do
    tr -d "[[:space:]]" < "$i" | 
      grep -q thisissometext && 
      printf "%s\n" "$i"
done
```

This loops over all arguments and uses the above test.

Answer (score 1):

The code below searches a directory recursively for files, removes all occurrences of `" "` and `"\n"`. If the string exists in the remaining text, there is a match. This implies that the spaces/newlines can be on *any* position in the string inside your file(s).

#### What it does

If it finds matching files, they will be printed in the terminal, including their paths, like:

```
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testmap/test2.txt
/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testmap/Naamloze map 2/test1.txt
```

The try / except I built in to prevent the script from breaking if it runs into an unreadable file.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

s = sys.argv[2]
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        file = root+"/"+file
        try:
            if s in open(file).read().replace(" ", "").replace("\n",""):
                print(file)
        except:
            pass
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `find_string.py`
2. Run it with the directory and the string as arguments:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/find_string.py <directory> <string_to_find>
   ```

   If either the string or the directory contains spaces, use quotes:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/find_string.py '<directory>' '<string_to_find>'
   ```

#### Note

The script, as it is finds files with the string, with either whitespaces or newlines in it. It can be expanded with other characters/strings (e.g. tabs) in the line:

```
if s in open(file).read().replace(" ", "").replace("\n",""):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep -i --recursive 'word1\|word2' *` and `awk '/word1/,/word2/'` can be used to deal with the newline

[image]

Comment: This does not work on *this string, or any variations of it with white spaces and/or newlines in the middle of it.*